# Why, oh why was this marked off-topic?

Tags: discussion

This is the question... in question (heh): [Patch cable wiring/colors](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30156/home-patch-cable)

I understand the question has the word "home" in it, and probably points to something based on home networking, but this one really is related to networking regardless of home/enterprise.  I fully understand the reason we keep it strictly to enterprise, and I understand there will be overlap that are marked off topic for other reasons.  But seriously, if mods just did OP a solid and just remove the word "home" from the question in an edit, or mark it as a duplicate of one of the many questions about cable termination.

What message does that send to new users?  There's a difference between marking questions as off topic, and being obsessive for the sake of semantics.  Asking questions here shouldn't be like applying for a passport.

We seriously need to learn to read between the lines a little bit, we're here to help people and answer their questions, not police it to death.  NESE has had a huge problem with quality questions in recent months, and while I'm sure the mods have an idea of 1000 other reasons for that, this is one that really isn't that hard to improve.

Comment: Even superuser/stackoverflow does not normally mark this as OT.

Comment: ...did you miss the part where the question has been reopened? So, uh, OP raised a question here in meta, I pointed out my istake, and corrected it.

Comment: Actually, I spent much less time recently applying for a U.S. passport renewal than I normally spend crafting a question for NE :).  Seriously, though.

Answer (score 7):

Completely agree with Jordan, that question really should not have been closed. This isn't the first time stuff like this gets brought up. A perfectly good *networking* question should not be closed just because someone mentions the word *home*.

Coupled with the recent less than positive posts on meta, I think the NESE community really needs to re-think their strategy and place.

Comment: I see the point about this Q, in this case the world "home" is insignificant. I'll edit and re-open. update: there's a min-chars limit, so I added some words to the Q also.

Comment: @CraigConstantine I think you referencing a search was perfectly fine, but the point is multiple users marked it off-topic because it wasn't PERFECTLY worded.

Comment: multiple *mods* did not matk it off-topic. I was the first mod to touch it.

Comment: Sorry my fault, edited.

Comment: @Eddie, in regards to your second paragraph, I wouldn't count a troll post and a post where the OP self edited to say he had a bad day and vented here as any sort of basis that NE needs to rethink things. Or did you have something else in mind? Also keep in mind that meta is often a place for users to state their dissatisfaction on any site in the network. It is how things change/improve, so a measure of "less than positive posts" are quite expected.

Comment: @Ylearn Of the 5 posts at the top of meta, four of them are negative ( [1](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/593) [2](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/594) [3](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/592) [4](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/587) ). One is my own, so you're welcome not to count that. But either way they all came in pretty close to each other, which I think is a reflection of the trend. Maybe "re-think things" was poorly worded, maybe a "course-correction" is more fitting.

Comment: And I've been meaning to post constructive suggestions in the other thread. But I haven't gotten around to it yet :(

Comment: @Eddie, #1 is troll post by someone upset that his [opinion based question](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/30161/33) was closed. Lots of "accusation" and nothing of any real merit. #2 questioned a closed action which was addressed by the mod in question so no real issue there. #3 is about voting, which is a problem with individuals in the community and something not addressable by the community. #4 was again OP self edited to say he had a bad day and vented here. So where is the trend of a problem in those four posts that can be addressed by the community?

Answer (score 5):

Remember, this is a "community" moderated site. If something shouldn't be closed, then the community can choose to express their opinion. You can choose to cast a "Leave Open" vote that offsets a close vote or you can cast a re-open vote on a question after it has been closed.

You can also edit the question to improve it, either to be voted on by the community or directly if you have the privilege.

Barring that, you can always bring the question to meta as has been done here.

Keep in mind that people (including the *volunteer* moderators) can make mistakes. Maybe they are busy and didn't have time to fully read/process the request to see if it could fit.

As members of the community, please use the tools available to you to help maintain the site.